# Storing the screen Texture inside HLSL texture variable (XNA)

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, hlsl

There is any way to store the screen texture in HLSL texture variable, without passing it from the C# code?

For instance, the current texture that is drowing can be accessed by using

```
sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);
```

There is any way to do the same for what is currently on the scrren?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I assume you are using SpriteBatch so register 0 is implicitly set to the current texture. 
To get the current pixels on the screen, you have to draw everything to a render target and then pass that render target to your HLSL.